# How to get the count of result from a pymongo aggregate?

Tags: python, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I am trying to get the result count of a pymongo `aggregate` method. The `aggregate` method returns a `command_cursor` object but according to the [pymongo docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) only the `cursor` object has a `count()` method. How do I get the count of the result of an `aggregate` function without using any kind of loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
result = list(db.collection.aggregate([...]))
print(len(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should return count from your aggregation:

```
pipeline = [
     {"$match": YOURQUERY},
     {"$group": {"_id": groupby, "count": {"$sum":1}}}, # this returns count
     {YOUR_PIPELINES}
]
cursor = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: doesn't this add a `count` field for each result returned?

Comment: It's a count for group of documents with some criterion. You can count by grouping documents, then pass this count to the next stage of pipeline.

Comment: It's either this answer or just do: len(list(cursor))

Comment: @ScamCast that is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't want to add a `$group` pipeline to my query so I needed something done using python. Please add that as an answer.